# I can't render pictures in an HTML generated PDF

Tags: c#, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pdf

I got an issu with the plugin IronPDF. I'm trying to render HTML and CSS display to a PDF files, it work in our web application, but now I'm trying to do the same stuff with a windows service. I tried to use Bootstrap locally to get CSS, that didn't work so I used CDN link and it worked. But now, I would like to use pictures, so I pasted a folder in the root of the project with pictures in it, I think it's an application root problem (Ibelieved that the application root was the root of the project, but it seems to be wrong)

I would like to have something like this:

https://prnt.sc/gvzvpg

but instead, I have something like that :

http://prntscr.com/gvzw1r

thanks for attention

Answer (score 0):

I used before ItexSharp for generating PDF files with c#. For images, the path must be relative path. try it

Comment: I know it must be relative, I use a relative path like :/Images/Site/test.png for exemple, but it doesn't work because the root of the execution context might be different than the project root